# How to edit a tuple of this query

Tags: mysql

I have written a query with 3 columns which stand for Name, HoursRegistered & HoursCompleted. After doing all my query selection i get the right table I want. But, my column of  HoursRegistered & HoursCompleted have some null values in them. I want to replace NULL with 0.Now, I know I have to use UPDATE. But, wherever I use UPDATE, it throws different errors and can't figure out where to use update. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks

```
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName," ",LastName) as Name, SUM(SUBQUERY.completed) 
   as HoursCompleted,SUM(SUBQUERY.registered) as HoursRegistered from
   (select Distinct e.EmployeeID,e.FirstName, e.LastName,
       case when t.Status='COMPLETED' then c.CreditHours else null end as completed,
       case when t.Status='REGISTERED' then c.CreditHours else null ends as registered
       from employee e left join Transcript t
       on e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeId
       left join class c
       on t.ClassId=c.ClassId
       group by e.EmployeeID,c.CreditHours ,e.FirstName, e.LastName,t.Status) 
       as SUBQUERY group by Employeeid,LastName
       ORDER BY LastName ASC
```

The error that I get when I run this query is

Comment: Nice error. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: This looks like it could be rewritten , can you add sample data to your question as text please.